# Delphi Rad Studio - Can I stop components being recompiled each time I compile/build

Tags: delphi, components

It might have something to do with library and other paths, but every time I build/compile software in DRS which uses a bought component like TMS controls the TMS controls keep getting recompiled, too.

How do I stop that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your building with Packages you can change the TMS Package build control setting from "Rebuild as Needed" to "Explicit Rebuild".

If the source of the TMS package then changes  your build will stop with:
Never-Build package 'NameOfChangedPackage' must be recompiled.

Another option that works if your building with or without packages, is to build with the DCUs.   First you need to remove TMS Source directories from your Library path and project path.   Then you need to open the TMS Package make sure it's project options knows of it's source.   Then also set the DCU or Unit Output Directory to a new directory.   With this you can rebuild TMS and find the new directory will be populated with the DCUs.  Add the DCU Folder to your Library Path, and it won't recompile TMS when building your project.

Beware:   If you compile TMS (or any other package) this way with debug information you may find yourself in the TMS source or the CPU Viewer.   If you want to avoid the CPU Viewer and step in the TMS source you will need to set the browsing path.   If you want to avoid stepping in the TMS Source all together make sure it's not compiled with debug information.

Answer (score 4):

Do you maybe include both source dirs and unit dirs of the components in your unitdir (Library path)

Try to only include the precompiled units in the unitdir (library path), and leave the sources of the components only in the browsing path. (for debugger use)

Comment: That sounds quite likely.  Dank U/grazie, Marco